# How do force textures to map to a vanishing point like distant traintracks?

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders

I want egyptian hieroglyphics to 'scroll' down the face of a pyramid, and stretch out horizontally as they reach the bottom. But at the moment they're refusing to shrink to the 'vanishing point' at the top of the pyramid. See screenshot.

[image]

They're just not facing the right way at all, and they're not being properly distorted either.

See what I mean? In my mind it should be as simple as just fiddling with the UVMap, but that hasn't been working. Are there are any easy alternatives that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You've got it backwards, I think. You shouldn't have to mess with the UVs at all, just manipulate the geo.

You want start with a cube shape, unwrap with all the sides taking up the full texture, or thereabouts.

[image]

Then delete the top. Scale those verts down to zero.

[image]

Then in order to correct the distortion, you have to subdivide the mesh. UVs aren't very good at "guessing" how to interpolate their position.

You can use a SubSurf modifier set to simple.

[image]

Done.